# jQuery masonry layout complete event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have followed the documentation exactly and the layout complete event isn't working. Example can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9464buy5/

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#items {
    width: 500px;
}
.item { 
    background: #ff0000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('#items');
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: 220,
        gutter: 20
    });

    $container.masonry('on', 'layoutComplete', function(msnryInstance, laidOutItems) {
        alert("");
    });
});
```

Anyone know if this a known bug or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah I've sorted it using the non jquery method. You have to call the following function after initialisation to trigger the event:

```
msnry.layout();
```

e.g

```
var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 220,
    gutter: 20
});

msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', function( msnryInstance, laidOutItems ) {
    alert("");
});

msnry.layout();
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code to do this in jQuery:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
    // disable initial layout
    isInitLayout: false,
    //...
});
// bind event
$grid.masonry( 'on', 'layoutComplete', function() {
    console.log('layout is complete');
});
// manually trigger initial layout
$grid.masonry();
```

This was taken from the bottom of this page: http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

Answer (score 4):

You can try for

```
var msnry = new Masonry( $container, {
     itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: 220,
        gutter: 20
  });
```

Then use:

```
msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', function( msnryInstance, laidOutItems ) {
    //custom code
  });
```

And trigger layout to call **layoutComplete** callback

```
msnry.layout();
```

Have look at **[this codepen](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/htsui)**

Comment: Yeah I tried that see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9464buy5/1/ still doesn't work though

Comment: @geoffs3310, use msnry.layout(); to trigger layoutComplete

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the event listener before you call `masonry()`

```
var $container = $('#items');
$container.on('layoutComplete', function() {
  console.log('complete');
});
$container.masonry({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  columnWidth: 220,
  gutter: 20
});
```

You can even make a chain:

```
$('#items').on('layoutComplete', function() {
  console.log('complete');
})
.masonry({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  columnWidth: 220,
  gutter: 20
});
```